# Parsing a large outlook mailbox with VBS

Tags: arrays, vbscript, outlook

I am writing a vbs that checks for an enclosed set of initials in an email subject for a given day, and then outputs a report based on the results. I have got it working, but it is very slow. The folder it is searching has several thousand emails in it, so it may just be down to that, but I was just wondering if anyone had any ideas regarding how to speed it up?

Below is the bit of code which is taking the time to execute. `Push` is just a helper function that puts the item into the array;

```
`For Each oItem In cItems
if TypeName(oItem) = "MailItem" then
dateTemp = Formatdatetime(oItem.ReceivedTime, 2)
    If datevalue(dateTemp) = datevalue(requiredDate) Then
    test = oItem.subject
        if mid(test, 1, 1) = "[" AND mid(test, 4, 1) = "]" then
            push subjectArray, test
        end if
    end if
end if
Next`
```

Comment: Your best bet is server-side message filtering. Give this a shot:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526895(v=exchg.10).aspx

Comment: Also, for the case that `subjectArray` is an actual array and `push` is a Sub that involves `ReDim Preserve`, you should switch to a Scripting.Dictionary for storage. Native arrays in VBS are wasteful, inflexible and not worth the hassle unless they are constant in size.

Comment: @Tomalak They are also far more efficient *(especially large datasets)* then using any form of COM object even the `Scripting.Dictionary`. Personally native arrays are as flexible as they need to be it just requires planning how you intend to use them, before finding you've come up short.

Comment: @Lankymart Of course, as long as you don't `ReDim Preserve` them in one-step increments for potentially thousands of times in a row, they are indeed more efficient. I was talking about this particular scenario, though.

Comment: FYI, CDO is deprecated: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2028411

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for parsing items quickly is to use a Table Object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869529.aspx

If you want the utmost in performance, use MAPI directly with C++ (or Redemption COM) with multi-threading.